# Regular Expressions - Semicolon passing unit test when not allowed character

Tags: c#, regex, nunit

I am attempting to write a file name validator for file upload in a web application. Following the [OWASP guidance](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload) modified slightly I started off with

```
public bool IsValidFileName(string filename)
{
    Regex validFileName = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{1,244}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}");
    return validFileName.IsMatch(filename);
}
```

The idea being to limit filename to alphanumeric, underscores, hyphens and spaces, with a single "." and a file extension. I then wrote a bunch of tests (NUnit), yet almost all of the ones that were supposed to assert false didn't.

Amending the regex to `"([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{1,244}).([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10})")` - added brackets around the length groups, removed the string literal and escape of "." now passes all tests except

```
    [Test]
    public void IsValidFileName_NameContainsSemiColon_ReturnsFalse()
    {
        // Arrange
        string filename = "MyFile;asp.jpg";

        // Act
        bool result = FileExtensions.IsValidFileName(filename);

        // Assert
        Assert.That(result, Is.False);
    }
```

Is there something special about a semicolon in C# regexes that I need to account for?

Comment: You do not use [start and end of line anchors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - `"^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{1,244}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}$"`

Comment: Adding the start and end anchors has solved my issue with this test, but it is a little strange because `string filename = "MyFile:asp.jpg";` was passing the equivalent test. Should the question actually be what is making the colon pass the test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex does not contain start (`^`) and end (`$`) characters, so is matching within your input string.  Change it to the following:

```
Regex validFileName = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{1,244}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}$");
```

Without using these, the test passes because it matches a substring of your filename.  In the example you gave, your regular expression match is shown in bold:

> MyFile;**asp.jpg**

Comment: Thanks for that - any idea why the colon passes, as per my comment to the original question

Comment: The semicolon is not matched by your expression - if you look at the value of the match you'll see it's only the bit after the filename.  Updated my answer to make this clearer.  Adding in the start and end markers forces it to only match the entire input string.

Comment: I get that, but why does `MyFile:asp.jpg` not match?

Comment: Using code copied and pasted from your question, MyFile:asp.jpg behaves exactly the same as MyFile;asp.jpg

Comment: Ok - guess I could have made a different mistake somewhere else. Thanks very much for taking the time to investigate

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use ^ and $ signs to match entire input string?

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{1,244}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}$
```